# How to get previous week particular day from given date?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

From the backend, I get the date of the array with this format "18/11 Wednesday", "19/11 Thursday",... Then I store this in an array in the frontend.

```
const sevenDays = [];

getData() {

  sevenDays.push(this.sales[x].values[i].date);

}
```

Now I need to get a particular day of last week from all the elements In this array. As an example,

```
sevenDays[0] = "18/11 Wednesday"
```

Output should be

```
newsevenDays[0] = "11/11 Wednesday"
```

Please give me help guys, I tried so many times.

Comment: Update the backend to use a standard format instead.

Comment: It is not really clear what exactly you trying to do. can you be more specific?

Comment: Cannot change the backend format @str

Comment: Sorry, I edited, and now can you clear it? Need to subtract 7 days from this type of date format. @wayneOS

Comment: The first thing to try is to create an actual date based on this. Have you tried [`moment(String, Format)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)? How do you handle years with that format anyway?

Comment: yes tried but I'm not familiar with the moment.js. No need to handle year. Only need to get a particular day from given date.

Comment: but to get the date 7 days ago, you need the year

Comment: Why? Example, please?

Answer (score 0):

To get the date 7 days before a date, you can use the subtract method of the moment.js package (docs below), but you need to get your dates in a right format before and insert it as a parameter of moment()

```
moment(new Date()).subtract(7, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
---> will return you the date of 7 days ago, with format DD/MM/YYYY
```

Docs: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/02-subtract/

Comment: So can you tell how to convert it into the right format, please? Because I tried this function already

Comment: yes but to convert you need at least, the day, the month and the year, and in your example you only get the day and the month

Comment: So without year, this couldn't do?

Comment: For example, you need to subtract 7 days from "25/11", it means you can use JS to subtract the first number before the " / " you can do it in JS, but if you want to remove 7 days from "01/11" you can't just do 01 - 7, you would need to do advanced functions and it's a bit too wasting time, you really can't format the date from backend ???

Comment: Yes, can't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native javascript function **Date()** without using **moment.js**

```
var arbitraryDate = new Date();
arbitraryDate.setDate(arbitraryDate.getDate()-5)
```

to see output in **MM/DD/YYYY** format.

```
arbitraryDate.toLocaleDateString()
```

Try running the code below

```js
var arbitraryDate = new Date();
arbitraryDate.setDate(arbitraryDate.getDate()-5)

foo = arbitraryDate.toLocaleDateString()
document.getElementById('arbitrary').innerHTML = foo
```

```html
<h4 id="arbitrary"></h4>
```

Comment: This is for the current date. In my case, I already get the date from the backend with that format that I mention there. This is not working for that format.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and I hope this should help if someone faces this kind of problem. The moment.js gives any custom format of the date convert into a standard format. So here first I give my custom format as a second parameter 'DD/MM dddd' in moment() function. Then you can give your final formats as well.

```
 finalDate = moment('18/11 Wednesday', 'DD/MM dddd').subtract(7,'days').format('DD/MM dddd');
```

output:

```
finalDate = 11/11 Wednesday
```